# Add taxonomy terms list to homepage Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Please help me to add taxonomy terms from custom taxonomy into home page. I have no idea how to do this as I'm coming from WordPress. In WordPress it is easy as calling get_terms(). I have following file as my home page: `mytheme/templates/page--front.html.twig`

I have more than one taxonomy type and all of them are going to queried in the home page.

How to query the taxonomy terms?

**UPDATE:**

I have created a new region called `home_content` in my `theme.info.yml` and I have created a view(block) for getting the taxonomy terms, added it to region in back-end and display it as `{{page.home_content}}`. It works but I have few questions.

1. I have fields for logo and text in the taxonomy. I want to list them too.
2. I need to customize the html. How can I do that?

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to code anything

1. Create view with taxonomy terms required. `Structure > Views > Create New View` and add block view for taxonomy terms. User `filter` section to select specific terms or dictionaries. Save the view.
2. Go to `Structure > Block Layout` and insert block with your view into desired region. In `visibility` section, `pages` tab: type `<front>` in pages and select `Show for the listed pages` in order to display it on home page only.

Above steps will display your required terms on home page.

To copy and modify template(s) in your theme, follow the instructions on drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2358785